# Proving an extension is Galois

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, galois-extensions

Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension with Galois group $G:=\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$; suppose $K$ contains the $p$-th roots of unity, $p$ a prime number.

Now, if $\alpha \in L^\times$, $\overline{\alpha} \in H^0(G,L^\times/(L^\times)^p)$, then $L(\alpha^{1/p})/K$ is  Galois, where $\overline{\alpha}$ denotes the class of $\alpha$ in $L^\times/(L^\times)^p$

What I know is that $L(\alpha^{1/p})/L$ is Galois with Galois group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, but this doesn't guarantee me that $L(\alpha^{1/p})/K$ is  Galois.

Comment: You are correct in that $L(\alpha^{1/p})/L$ being Galois does not guarantee that $L(\alpha^{1/p})/K$ would be Galois *in general*. You really *need* the assumption that $\alpha$ is $G$-invariant modulo $p$th powers.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen and with that assumption how can I prove is Galois? And I have also some problems understanding the cohomology group: what I know is that $H^0(G,A)=A^G$, but I don't know how it looks like in this case

Comment: The argument is in nguyen quang do's answer, I think. Consider the following example. Let $K=\Bbb{Q}$ and $L=K(\sqrt2)$. $K$ contains the second root of unity. With $\alpha=2+\sqrt2$ we see that $L(\alpha^{1/2})$ will be a Galois extension of $K$, because it will also contain the square roots of the conjugate $\overline{\alpha}=2-\sqrt2$. All because $\alpha\cdot\overline{\alpha}=2$ has a square root in $L$. Clearly $\alpha\overline{\alpha}\in (L^\times)^2$ is equivalent to the condition $\alpha (L^\times)^2=\overline{\alpha}(L^\times)^2$.

Comment: (cont'd) Which, in turn, is equivalent to saying that the coset $\alpha(L^\times)^2$ is invariant under the action of $Gal(L/K)$ in $L^\times/(L^\times)^2$.

Comment: I think I'm still a bit lost. Now $L(\alpha^{1/p})$ is Galois over $K$ because it contains also the $p$-th roots of the conjugates of $\alpha$?

Comment: (cont'd) But for example with $\alpha=1+\sqrt2$ we see that  $L(\alpha^{1/2})$ won't be a Galois extension of $K$. It cannot contain square roots of $\overline{\alpha}=1-\sqrt2$ for $L(\alpha^{1/2})$ is real, and $1-\sqrt2<0$. Also, this time $(1-\sqrt2)(1+\sqrt2)=-1$, a non-square in $L$. Implying that the coset $(1+\sqrt2)(L^\times)^2$ is not a $G$-invariant.

Comment: Correct, if $m(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$, then the argument from nguyen quang do's answer shows that $L(\alpha^{1/p})$ is the splitting field of the (separable) polynomial $m(x^p)$ over $K$. Hence it is Galois.

Comment: Oops. I seem to have thought that $L=K(\alpha)$. I think the argument survives though. Thinking...

Comment: May be a better argument would be that $L$ is a splitting field of some polynomial $f(x)$ over $K$, and then $L(\alpha^{1/p})$ is a splitting field of $f(x)m(x^p)$.

Comment: Why $\alpha \overline{\alpha} \in (L^\times)^2$ is equivalent to $\alpha (L^\times)^2= \overline{\alpha}  (L^\times)^2$? Shouldn't it be equivalent to $\alpha (L^\times)^2= \overline{\alpha}^{-1}  (L^\times)^2$?

Comment: $L^\times/(L^\times)^2$ is 2-torsion. Every square is modded out :-)

Answer (score 2):

I keep all your notations, noting only that the $p$-th root $\alpha ^{1/p}$ is defined up to a $p$-th root  of unity $\zeta$, but the cyclic extension $L(\alpha ^{1/p})$ does not depend on $\zeta$ which belongs to $L$. A classical criterion for $L/K$ to be Galois is that $L(\alpha ^{1/p})$ is stabilized by any extension $S$ of any $s\in G$ to a normal closure of $L(\alpha ^{1/p})$. By hypothesis $s(\alpha)=\alpha. \beta^p$, with $\beta \in L^*$ (this is just the explicitation of the invariance of $\bar\alpha$ under the action of $G$). So necessarily $S(\alpha ^{1/p})$ has the form $S(\alpha ^{1/p})=\alpha^{1/p}. \beta. \zeta $ , hence belongs to $L(\alpha ^{1/p})$, and we are done.

Comment: Well, $K$ contains all the $p$-th roots of unity and thus also $L$. Moreover, I know already that $L/K$ is Galois